# Worksheet Names to a row

Tags: excel, vba

Complete beginner for VBA so simpler the better.
I want to collect all sheet names in excel and insert them to the first row. I'm able to collect the names with macro that I found (bellow) but I don't know how to convert the values to be in the first row only and not in the first column?

```
Sub TestNames()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long

For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
LR = Worksheets("Worksheet Names").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
'This LR varaible to find the last used row
Cells(LR, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Ws.Name
Next Ws
    
End Sub
```

[https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-name-worksheet/#:~:text=In%20VBA%2C%20to%20name%20a,its%20name%20using%20Worksheet%20object](https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-name-worksheet/#:%7E:text=In%20VBA%2C%20to%20name%20a,its%20name%20using%20Worksheet%20object).

Comment: If there are 5 worksheets, where do you want to write their names? `A1:A5` (column), `A1:E1` (row) or somewhere else? Is this code located in the workbook containing these worksheets?

Comment: A1:E1 (row)
Yes, code is in the workbook containing these worksheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Worksheet Names to First Row

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TestNames()
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Worksheet Names")

    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Long
    
    For Each sws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        c = c + 1
        dws.Cells(1, c).Value = sws.Name
    Next sws
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Very close, just check for last column, and re-arrange `Cells(LR, 1).Select`
like in example below.
Keep in mind, finding last row and last column is not very straight forward task, there are different methods, - investigate them and apply the one which fits the best.

```
Sub TestNames()

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim LastColumn As Long

For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
'LR = Worksheets("Worksheet Names").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
LastColumn = Worksheets("Worksheet Names").Cells(1, Worksheets("Worksheet Names").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1


Worksheets("Worksheet Names").Cells(1, LastColumn).Value = Ws.Name

Next Ws
    
End Sub
```